# How to Query Multiple Django Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have been having a difficult time finding a relevant example within the Django documentation or a similar example online about how to most efficiently query the below models.

These models store data about sales employees, their teams, their weekly goals, and their actual production.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

class TeamMembers(models.Model):
    team_name = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

class Goal(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

class Production(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    week = models.DateField()
    quantify = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

Given a prompted date range I would like to display a page with a table for each team, the team members during that range (teams can change members), and their performances against their goals (goals can change weekly) as such:

```
Time Period: 4/1/2018 - 4/28/2018

TEAM EAST    Week 4/1      Week 4/7
Team Member  Goal  Actual  Goal   Actual
Joe          1000  1100    900    750
Mel          750   600     650    650

TEAM WEST    Week 4/1      Week 4/7
Team Member  Goal  Actual  Goal   Actual
Kim          1000  1100    900    750
Pat          750   600     650    650
```

My inclination was to first get the active teams during that date range, then loop through the teams to get the active team members, then loop through the team members to get their goals, production during those ranges, storing all of this in nested dictionaries. But there are roughly 10 teams and 100 team members, so it feels like that would be a lot of querying.

Is there a more efficient way of getting Teams, Members, Goals, and Production in a dictionary that I can use to present the data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To try something simple:
The following should give you all the team members by team in the date range, you can work through it ahead. Using select_related is important optimize. I use the debug-toolbar to check the performance.
Update to model:

```
class TeamMembers(models.Model):
    team_name = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='team_member_team_name')

Team.objects.filter(start_date='', end_date='').select_related('manager').prefetch_related(Prefetch('team_member_team_name', queryset=TeamMembers.objects.all().select_related('employee_id')))
```